# Selenium not scraping through all the tweets

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter

I am using auto scroll to scroll through a twitter feed to get all the tweets of a handle. It scrolls through the whole thing, but the `page_source` for my driver only has information about the end of the page where all tweets end and not of the beginning.

```
def scroll(url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(url) 
    driver.execute_script("var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000); function myTimer() { window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);console.log(document.documentElement.scrollHeight)}")
    oldVal = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY;") # Find position of scrollbar
    sleep(3)
    while oldVal != driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY;"):
        oldVal = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY;")
        sleep(4)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    return page_source
```

Comment: Try without the `--headless` option.

Comment: @Jortega Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This will scroll down dynamic pages :
(You should put your code in the `while` loop to repeat it each time before scrolling to the bottom of the page)

```
while True:

    # Scroll down to the bottom of the page:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait for the page to load:
    time.sleep(3)

    # Calculate new scroll height:
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```